# How do you add an SVG with no loc to an xml sitemap?

Tags: xml-sitemap

I'm trying to add an xml sitemap to my site via Google instructions at https://support.google.com/webmasters/answer/183668?hl=en&ref_topic=4581190.  My primary goal is to include metadata about several SVGs on my page.  These SVGs are defined without a url, and then used later as containers for NVD3 charts like so:

```
<div id='chart'>
    <svg style='height:600px; width:100%'> </svg>
</div>
```

However, the sitemap process appears to identify images based on their location.  How can I add these svgs to my sitemap, or is this not possible?

Comment: Same question I have. Hope someone gives solution.